# Laracogs installation issue

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to install laracogs ([github](https://github.com/YABhq/Laracogs)). I'm having the following output

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Laravel/laracogs$ composer require "yab/laracogs"
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Using version ^2.0 for yab/laracogs
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yab/formmaker v1.0.4 requires laravelcollective/html ^5.3|^5.3-dev -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[5.3.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for yab/laracogs ^2.0 -> satisfiable by yab/laracogs[v2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - yab/laracogs v2.0.0 requires yab/formmaker ^1.0 -> satisfiable by yab/formmaker[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3, v1.0.4].
    - yab/formmaker v1.0.0 requires laravelcollective/html ^5.2|^5.1 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.2, v5.2.1, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4].
    - yab/formmaker v1.0.1 requires laravelcollective/html ^5.2|^5.1 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.2, v5.2.1, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4].
    - yab/formmaker v1.0.2 requires laravelcollective/html ^5.2|^5.1 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.2, v5.2.1, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4].
    - yab/formmaker v1.0.3 requires laravelcollective/html ^5.2|^5.1 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.2, v5.2.1, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.0 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.1 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.2 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.3 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.4 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.5 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.6 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.7 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.8 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.9 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2.1 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2.2 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2.3 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2.4 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
     ...
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have put the composer.json file to Laravel 5.3 but that does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you read the error message? It seems that your package is trying to grab `yab/formmaker` too, which needs `laravelcollective/html` installed also. My suggestion would be to try installing `laravelcollective/html` and then retry your installation.

Comment: Yes I did read it. Solution was to add     "minimum-stability": "dev" and    "prefer-stable" : true to composer.json. There seems to be an issue with laravelcollection.hml and Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true,
```

to the composer.json file.The reason is because Laracogs depends on laravelcollective/html package, for which the 5.3 version is only in dev state